# split() method complications for chopping initial string

Tags: java, split

I have Macro Processing for my SQL file in one of the TDD,- Test Driven Development project.

> --> is the Macro Marker

I have used \p{space}+ posix standard regex split.

```
sqlLine.split("\\p{space}+");
```

In this case, Macro has to start after a white space. Only then my split works. Hence I added to handle `NoSpaceInMacroStartup` case. While I do that I observed split behaves differently with respect `System.out.println()` and for direct indexing.

```
macroToken = macroToken.split("-->")[1]; //gives the first token after markup

//But While I examine

//gives the first token after markup
System.out.println("[0]->"+macroToken.split("-->")[0]) 

//And next index throws exception
System.out.println("[1]->"+macroToken.split("-->")[1])
```

I would like to know why split behaves differently.

While I do Inspection for the following line in debug mode.

macroToken = **macroToken.split("-->")**[1];

It is

> [0]=""
>
> [1]="Within"

Because of this variance, I have used,-

```
macroToken = macroToken.replaceFirst("-->","");
```

Someone please explain the behavior of split() for direct indexing and its run-time behavior.

Comment: While I frame the Question itself I had realized a bit, that there is no run-time variance. It had happened because of the assignment to same variable to itself. For next time, it didn't find the macro marker, which was used as a logic as markup `-->`. So index [1] fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once following line is executed string token `macroToken`  is been overwritten.

```
macroToken = macroToken.split("-->")[1];
```

Hence that, you weren't able get the same set of index again for `System.out.prinln()`

And answering the question if `split()` method is used to chop the String in Java, there will be empty string in case of matched string which is used in `split()`. Here you are matching starting string "-->" hence,

> [0]=""
>
> [1]="Within"